# MVC JQuery Dialog Client Validation

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-ui-dialog, unobtrusive-validation

Why does validation not work here? I have a link that when clicked opens a dialog loading its content from a partial view. I want to validate the form when the button on the dialog is clicked.  I load the validation scripts in the layout file.

```
$dialog  = $<'<div></div>');
$('.linkClass').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: this.href,
                type: "GET",
                success: function (result) {
                    $dialog.load(this.url).dialog({
                        resize: "auto",
                        width: 490,
                        height: 430,
                        modal: true,
                        buttons: {
                            Save: function () {
                                if ($dialog.find('form:first').valid()) {
                                    $.ajax({
                                        url: "/Home/Dates",
                                        type: "POST",
                                        data: $('form').serialize(),
                                        datatype: "html",
                                        success: function (result) {
                                            $dialog.dialog('close');
                                        },
                                        error: function (xhr, testStatus, error) {alert("Error occured: " + error + " " + xhr + " " + testStatus) }
                                    });*/
                                }
                                else { alert("Please correct the errors on the form") }
                            },
                            Cancel: function () {
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                   $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($dialog.find('form:first').valid());
                    $dialog.dialog('open');

                },

                error: function (request, status, error) {
                    alert(request.responseText);
                }
            });

        });
```

However, this does not work. I can see that my validation scripts have loaded properly. Also, when I add the scripts in the partial view that is loaded in the dialog, validation works well. Why is that so? Why do I need to load these scripts in two places?

Answer (score 0):

When you specify a jQuery function such as 
    $('.linkClass').click(function (e) {...
it must be executed after the element with class ID .linkClass has been loaded/generated. jQuery attaches a copy of its nested function to each element in that class, so if your jQuery is being executed before the page has fully loaded, it will not validate. 
Try nesting this jQuery function inside a JavaScript function and executing it when the page has loaded.

```
function whenLoaded(){
    $('.linkClass').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: this.href,
            type: "GET",
            success: function (result) {
                $dialog.load(this.url).dialog({
                    resize: "auto",
                    width: 490,
                    height: 430,
                    modal: true,
                    buttons: {
                        Save: function () {
                            if ($dialog.find('form:first').valid()) {
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: "/Home/Dates",
                                    type: "POST",
                                    data: $('form').serialize(),
                                    datatype: "html",
                                    success: function (result) {
                                        $dialog.dialog('close');
                                    },
                                    error: function (xhr, testStatus, error) {alert("Error occured: " + error + " " + xhr + " " + testStatus) }
                                });*/
                            }
                            else { alert("Please correct the errors on the form") }
                        },
                        Cancel: function () {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        }
                    }
                });
}
```

Also I'd recommend not having an AJAX request nested inside the success function of a parent AJAX request. You should validate your for in plain JavaScript and upon success, call the AJAX request. You shouldn't need to use a form for AJAX requests either since forms are submitted using POST, not AJAX.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The code above is found inside my document.ready function to ensure that the element with that class is already present. I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "You should validate your for in plain JavaScript". Don't I need an ajax call to 1)Load the content of the dialog and 2) submit any form in the dialog? How else can I have the dialog buttons handle the submit action of the form?